# How can I save array Schema with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to save the categories that a user selected(business, tech, sports...) in a user collection that has a categories array using mongoose.

This is my users Schema and the categories array where I want to save the users categories.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({
  nick:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  categories:[{
    type: String
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: you have getting any error.?

Comment: No, I want to know how can I do it

Comment: you want store array in categories

Comment: I want to store categories that the users selected in the categories array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
categories: [
  {
    type: String
  }
]
```

To

```
categories: [
   category: {
      type: String
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({

  categories:{
    type: array,
    "default": []
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

you can define  categories type array and store array of ids and string

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate schema for categories.
2. Use mongoose ref concept inside the categories array in user schema

eg:

```
categories:[
    {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Categories'}
]
```

Comment: Why make another schema just for holding array elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your Schema looks okay to me. Are you asking how to actually insert data into the categories with the defined Schema?

Also, you might want to add an _id: false to your category array schema, otherwise all entries will automatically be given an _id by mongoose.

```
categories:[{
    _id: false,
    type: String
}]
```

To insert data into the categories you can do the following:

```
// Get a user for the example.
const user = await UserModel.findOne({});

// Add the business category to the set. If you just push, then you'll end up with duplicates. AddToSet adds them if they don't already exist. user.categories.addToSet('business');
await user.save();
```

Of course, you don't have to use async await with this, the same thing will work with callbacks.

```
UserModel.findOne({}, function(err, user) {
  if (!err) {
    user.addToSet('business');
    user.save();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by various way

```
var Empty1 = new Schema({ any: [] });
var Empty2 = new Schema({ any: Array });
var Empty3 = new Schema({ any: [Schema.Types.Mixed] });
var Empty4 = new Schema({ any: [{}] });
```

Why you don't refer official doc for the same.
[mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)